# App crashed when save button is clicked

Tags: php, android, mysql, image

> I wonder is it possible to update the image path and image in the
>   folder ?

I've been successfully stored the image path and text into `MySQL` from android, and save the image in a directory.

[image]

**Php for upload image**

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( !empty( $_POST['listItems'] ) ){
            $listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true ); 
            $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "androiddb");
            if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";
            $sql="INSERT INTO `staff_benefit` 
                 ( `type`, `amount`, `description`, `image`, `ts_id` ) 
                  VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
            if($stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql )){
                $url="http://192.168.1.7:80/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/";
                foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 
                    $id = uniqid();
                    $image_name = $id.".png";
                    $save_path = 'PhotoUpload/'.$image_name;
                    $image_url = $url.$image_name;
                    $bytes=file_put_contents($save_path, base64_decode($item['image']));
                    if( !$bytes ){
                        echo 'Error saving image';  
                    }else{
                        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', 
                        $item['type'], 
                        $item['amount'], 
                        $item['description'], 
                        $image_url, 
                        $item['ts_id'] );
                        if( !$res=$stmt->execute()){ 
                            echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

In **Edit_Staff_Benefit_ListView**, the two row data will be retrieved and loaded into `listView`. When list get clicked, it will intent to **Edit_Staff** for edit.

**Edit_Staff_Benefit_ListView**

```
 listViewEdit.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition = position; // update
                long i1d = staffs.get(position).getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Staff.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", i1d);
                intent.putExtra("ID", ID);  // this is ts_id
                intent.putExtra("mClickedPosition", mClickedPosition);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
```

**Edit_Staff**

```
  mClickedPosition=getIntent().getIntExtra("mClickedPosition",-1);
            ID = getIntent().getLongExtra("id", 0);
            IDFromInfo=getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID" + ID+"FK"+IDFromInfo , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                RetrieveDetails(ID);  // retrieve all the data based on position in listView
            }


  save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     // if save button clicked
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                claimType = spinnerType.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Description = description.getText().toString();
                Amount = amount.getText().toString();
                if(mClickedPosition==-1)
                {
                 //Add(claimType,Amount,Description,photo);
                }
                else
                {
                    update(claimType,Amount,Description,photo);
                }

            }
        });
```

**update function**

```
 public void update( final String claimType,  final String Amount, final String Description, final Uri photo)
    {
           class updateImageAndText extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
               ProgressDialog loading;
               @Override
               protected void onPreExecute() {
                   super.onPreExecute();
                   loading = ProgressDialog.show(Edit_Staff.this,"Updating...","Wait...",false,false);
               }

               @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                   super.onPostExecute(s);
                   loading.dismiss();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   try {
                       Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                       returnIntent.putExtra("ClaimType", claimType);
                       returnIntent.putExtra("Amount", Amount);
                       returnIntent.putExtra("Description", Description);
                       returnIntent.putExtra("photo", photo);
                       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                       finish();
                   }catch(Exception e)
                   {

                   }
               }

               @Override
               protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                   HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                   hashMap.put(Configs.KEY_ID,String.valueOf(ID));
                   hashMap.put(Configs.KEY_TYPE,claimType);
                   hashMap.put(Configs.KEY_AMOUNT,Amount);
                   hashMap.put(Configs.KEY_DESCRIPTION,Description);
                   hashMap.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE,photo.toString());
                   RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                   String s = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.URL_UPDATEDE_IMAGE_TEXT,hashMap);
                   return s;
               }
           }
```

**Update.php**

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        //Getting values 

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $image = $_POST['image'];


        //importing database connection script 
        require_once('dbConnect.php');


        $sql = "UPDATE staff_benefit 
                  SET type = '$type', amount = '$amount', description='description', image='image' 
                WHERE id = '$id'";

        //Updating database table 
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo ' Updated Successfully';
        }else{

            echo mysqli_error($con);
            exit;
        }

        //closing connection 
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

App crashed when save button is clicked.Is it because I'm wrote a wrong update. php ? Thanks

**LogCat**

```
01-16 19:36:51.373  22786-22786/com.example.project.myapplication E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.Edit_Staff has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42c71d80 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,324} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:467)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:104)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.Edit_Staff$1updateImageAndText.onPreExecute(Edit_Staff.java:154)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.Edit_Staff.update(Edit_Staff.java:191)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.Edit_Staff$1.onClick(Edit_Staff.java:103)
```

Comment: add the full log, this is just a part of it

Comment: @meda http://pastebin.com/8f1Qr2Hc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Tony` when you get this error, it means your window is leaking the progress dialog.

This happens when you don't cancel it, it happened because your app crashes before that.

To see the real error remove `ProgressDialog loading;` for the sake of debugging.

Also you have a logic issues, your code should check if an image has been selected or not and add it to your `hashmap`.

If `Uri` is not initialized and you don't check that you will be getting `nullpointerException`.

You also need to send the image encoded in Base64 like you did in your old question. the uri is the path to the file on your device which you need for encoding, but it is not to be inserted in  your table.You need to reupload the new image instead.

Your PHP script should check for the parameters being passed. if the photo did not change do not updated that field you can have a condition checking `$_POST['image']` if it is not set run the `UPDATE` query without the image column.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity.

his error can be a little misleading in some circumstances (although the answer is still completely accurate) - i.e. in my case an unhandled Exception was thrown in an AsyncTask, which caused the Activity to shutdown, then an open progressdialog caused this Exception.. so the 'real' exception was a little earlier in the log.

Call dismiss() on the Dialog you created in before exiting your Activity, e.g. in onPause() or onDestroy().

Originaly answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Comment: How can I solve this ? where should I call dismiss() ?

Comment: Do this loading = new ProgressDialog.show(Edit_Staff.this,"Updating...","Wait...",false,false);

Comment: Try remove your onPreExecute, just to see what is happening. And remove  finish(); from jour try/catch block.

Comment: 01-16 21:04:33.818    6041-6368/com.example.project.myapplication `E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 6041
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)`

Comment: Error pointed to    `hashMap.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE,photo.toString());`